# Function including random number that can be inverted without the random number

Tags: algorithm, encryption

Given a number x and a random number n, I am looking for two functions F and G so that:

- y = F(x, n) where y is different for different values of n
- x = G(y)

all numbers are (large, e.g. 256 bit) integers

For instance given a list of numbers k1, k2, k3, f4 generated by applying multiple times F, it is possible to calculate k3 from k4 but not k4 from k3 (the random number prevents the inversion).

The problem is obvious if we allow to use n (or derived) in G (it is basically an asymmetric encryption) but this is not the target.

Any idea?

### Update

I found a function that works with infinite precision F = x * pow(coprime(x), n)

```
x = 29
p = 5
n = 20

def f(x,n):
    return x * pow(p,n) 

f(x,n) => 2765655517578125
```

and G becomes

```
def g(y):
    x = y
    while x % p == 0:
        x = x/p
    return x
g(y) = 29
```

Unfortunately this fails with overflow as soon as numbers become big (limited precision)

## Second update: the problem has no solution

In fact let's start from a situation where the problem has a solution, which is when the domain of G and F is R.
In that case choosing a random output from any function F' that has multiple output will work.

For instance if then F(x, n) = acos(x) + 2nπ, where n random is Integer

then G(y) = cos(y). From y is always possible to go back to x, but not the opposite without knowing n.
A similar example can be built with operation with module, which will work with Integer domains without the need of real numbers.

Anyway this will fail when the domain is the same finite set (like on physical memory) for F and G. It can be proved by contradiction.

Let's assume that for finite domains D1=D2 of size N, a function F:D1->D2 exists that produces M outputs where M > 1.
Assuming that the function produces at least one output for each x in D1,
1 either D2 > D1
2 or outputs from F are the same for different values of x (some overlapping must exists)

Now 1 is against the requirement that D1=D2, while 2 is against the requirement that G(y) has a single output value

If we relax 1 and we allow D2 > D1, then we can solve the problem. This can be done by adding n (or a derivation of it) like suggested in some comments. For my specific scenario probably it makes more sense to use a EC public/private key but that is another story.

Many Thanks

Comment: Carefully re-read your question and correct all the typos. I see at least one, and the rest of the question doesn't make sense, perhaps because of additional typos. As it stands, your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you sure *x = G(x)* is correct?

Comment: @Berthur thanks. I fixed and added some more content

Comment: @erikson thanks. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @Francesco What is the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of `x`>?  All _floating point_, all finite _floating point_,, all `int`, all _integer_, what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica all numbers are integers, potentially large integers because I want to use them as key for AES256. Thanks

Comment: The update doesn't make sense to me. What is `coprime(x)`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk. Why it does not make sense? It is runnable python code that solves the problem (unfortunately only assuming infinite precision, while here we want to limit to 256bits). Coprime is a number that does not divide the other number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).
If you don't use a coprime, in the function G, you do not stop at the value x. Coprimes are used in RSA.

Comment: @Francesco You require that you can find any predecessor *k_i* to *k_j* where *i < j*. Then my question is, is the random number *n* the same in all iterations? Or must this condition hold even if you use different random numbers on each iteration (that would be impossible btw).

Comment: @Berthur, yea it should be different at each iteration. And you are right the problem is not solvable when the set is finite. I will write a proof later

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, the following should work. If there is some other requirement that I did not understand from your question, please clarify, because this seems to suffice based on your definition. In that case, I will change or delete this answer.

```
f(x, n) = x | n;
g(y | n) = y;
```

where `|` means concatenation of bits. We can assign a fixed (maximum) number of bits for `n` and pad with zeros.

Comment: Not sure what encrypt is in this case.
 
Also looks like that n is in practice an input for g (because you concat n while calculating f), which we don't want because then the length would grow at each iteration.

The idea is that n matters to generate f(x, n) but someway there is a way to get rid of it in g(x) without knowing it. I added a sample that works with infinite precision but would fail on limited numbers. Perhaps the key is to find a function that works with modular exponentiation.

Comment: @Francesco Ok so you don't need any actual encryption going on? Then I'll remove that part. So is it a requirement that the output of `f` have the same length as the input?

Comment: Or you could concatenate with a '1' bit followed by n '0' bits. That way you can recover the value of `n` in `g` without knowing it in advance.

Comment: @Berthur, yes the idea is that it should be same length (or same precision to be precise). Encryption is not needed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  this would be simply an encoding of n, so you still have n in the input to g. The problem with concatenation is that you are increasing the number of needed bits, which we want to avoid. The idea is that x and y should both be 256 bits (to be used as key for AES256)

Answer (score 0):

there can be no solution for this problem because:
for a constant x1 and variable r you would have an output set with all Integers in it.
for a constant x2 and variable r again you would have an output set with all Integers in it.
so at best you can have a function g which would take a number from the output set of function f and return all possible answers which are infinite.
this is similar to writing a reverse hashing function; which defies logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure to understand the rationale here. There is nothing wrong in a reverse hash function: it is simply a function with multiple output (like sqrt) and I need only one (random) output to solve the problem. Perhaps you gave a good suggestion

Comment: my point is that for any given y, function g would have infinite outputs just like a reverse hash function.